# Can't login using CodeIgniter with query builder

Tags: sql, codeigniter-3, query-builder, codeigniter-query-builder

I am creating an application where in a user can register and login in order to add a task and to achieve that, I try to make use of a query builder. However, I can't able to login the user using that. Here is the sample snippet of my code to which I am using query builder in **Code Igniter**:

```
public function login_user($username = null, $password = null){
            if (is_null($username) || is_null($password) {
                return false;
            }else{
                if (password_verify($password, $db_password)) {

                    $db_password = $result->row(6)->password;

                    $result = $this->db->where('username', $username)
                              where('password', $password)
                              ->get('users');

                               if(!empty($result)){
                                    return $result->row(0)->id;
                                }return false;
                            }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got that to work after modifying some of the code itself. The reason I am not being able to login is the fact that I am fetching the database after the password verify and that will not work and it will not fetch the result of the `$db_password` variable. Here is some of the modifications of my code which I got it to work:

```
public function login_user($username = null, $password = null){
            if(is_null($username) || is_null($password)){
                return false;
            }else{
                $this->db->where('username', $username);

                $result = $this->db->get('users');

                $db_password = $result->row(6)->password;

                if(!empty($result)){
                    //Decrypt password from database when the user logs in 
                    if (password_verify($password, $db_password)) {

                        return $result->row(0)->id;

                    }return false;
                }return false;  
            }
```